# Instability in asynchronous distributed tensorflow training

Tags: tensorflow

I've been experimenting with using distributed Tensorflow on a language modeling task with two to three workers and a single parameter server. My workers are doing asynchronous gradient updates. This setup is definitely more efficient in terms of number of gradient updates per second but I'm able to get a lower error faster by just using a single training process.

Are there any tips to getting distributed training to work?

Is it important that there not be too many gradient updates per second?

Do I need to use a much lower learning rate? What should I be trying?

Another thing I noticed is that when using distributed training some mini batches can have a log loss that is 50 times bigger than what is expected. I'm curious what could be causing these spikes in the cost function and if it is important.

Comment: It seems like using a lower learning rate when doing distributed training might be part of the solution. I would still like to hear the advice of someone with more experience than myself.